# Power Shell Get-ADUser output in HTML

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Power Shell. Trying to get an output of how many user has been created in the last 30 days in an AD environment and output it as HTML. The following output is giving me the exact output I need-

```
$DateCutOff = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$UserCreated30Days = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property whenCreated | where { $_.whenCreated -gt $DateCutOff } | FT Name, whenCreated -Autosize
```

But when I'm adding `ConvertTo-HTML`, the output is not passing to the HTML output. This is my code-

```
$header = @"
<style>
    h1 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #e68a00;
        font-size: 28px;
    }
 
    h2 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #000099;
        font-size: 16px;
    }  
    
   table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 0px; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    
    td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 0px;
        border: 0;
    }
    
    th {
        background: #395870;
        background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #f0f0f2;
    }
    

    #CreationDate {

        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #ff3300;
        font-size: 12px;

    }
</style>
"@
$DateCutOff = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$UserCreated30Days += Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property whenCreated | where { $_.whenCreated -gt $DateCutOff } | FT Name, whenCreated -Autosize | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property Name,WhenCreated -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>User created in 30 days</h2>"
$Report = ConvertTo-Html -Body "$UserCreated30Days" -Head $header -Title "Active Directory Report" -PostContent "<p id='CreationDate'>Creation Date: $(Get-Date)</p>"
$Report | Out-File .\AD_Report-v5.html
```

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

MMA

Answer (score 0):

I fix your code. Maybe this code could be optimize, obviously but could be something like this:

```
$HTMLHeader = $null
$HTML_Body = $null
$HTMLEnd = $null
$HTMLHeader = @"
<html><head><title>Reporte de recursos en Azure</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #e68a00;
    font-size: 28px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000099;
    font-size: 16px;
}
table {
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 0px; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
} 

td {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0;
}

th {
    background: #395870;
    background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f0f0f2;
}


#CreationDate {

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ff3300;
    font-size: 12px;

}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>"@
$DateCutOff = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$USR_DB = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property whenCreated | where { $_.whenCreated -gt $DateCutOff }
$HTML_Body+="<table border=""0"" width=""100%"" cellpadding=""4""  style=""font-size:8pt;font-family:Segoe UI,Frutiger,Frutiger Linotype,Dejavu Sans,Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif;""><tr bgcolor=""#000099"">"
$HTML_Body+= "<th colspan= ""14"" ><font color=""#FFFFFF"">Users creation report</font></th></tr>"
$HTML_Body+="<tr bgcolor=""#0000FF"">"
$HTML_Body+="<th align=""center""><font color=""#FFFFFF"">Username</font></th>"
$HTML_Body+="<th align=""center""><font color=""#FFFFFF"">WhenCreated</font></th>"
$HTML_Body+="</tr>"
$HTML_Body+="<tr align=""center"" bgcolor=""#dddddd"">"
foreach ($USR in $USR_DB){
$INT_ALT_RW = 0

$HTML_Body+="<tr"
#region linea intercaladas
if ($INT_ALT_RW)
{
    $HTML_Body+=" style=""background-color:#dddddd"""
    $INT_ALT_RW=0
} else
{
    $INT_ALT_RW=1
}
#endregion linea intercaladas

$HTML_Body+=">"
$HTML_Body+="<td align=""center""><font color=""#000000"">$($USR.UserPrincipalName)</font></td>" 
$HTML_Body+="<td align=""center""><font color=""#000000"">$($USR.whenCreated)</font></td>"}
$HTML_Body+="</table>"
$HTML_Body+="</div>"
$HTMLEnd = "</body></html>"
$HTMLFile = $HTMLHeader + $HTML_Body + $HTMLEnd
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($HTMLFile) | Out-File .\temporal.html
```

I testing on my AD testing enviroment and works!

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. The problem is this line:

```
$UserCreated30Days += Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property whenCreated | where { $_.whenCreated -gt $DateCutOff } | FT Name, whenCreated -Autosize | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property Name,WhenCreated -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>User created in 30 days</h2>"
```

and more specifically the  `| FT Name, whenCreated -Autosize` part. `Format-Table` is only for output and is never to be used in a pipeline, as it destroys all objects.

Change that to `Select-Object` instead so the line looks like this and it works fine:

```
$UserCreated30Days += Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property whenCreated | where { $_.whenCreated -gt $DateCutOff } | Select-Object Name, whenCreated  | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>User created in 30 days</h2>"
```

I also remove the `-Property` part of ConvertTo-Html as it's not necessary, since we already narrowed down the properties we want with `Select-Object`.